# Calculate the carry over from rows based on criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` like this :

```
date        time    value
2021-08     0.0     22.50
2021-08     5.0     6600.00
2021-09     0.0     1057.62
2021-09     1.0     646.35
2021-09     2.0     311.76
2021-09     3.0     3982.50
2021-09     4.0     900.00
2021-09     7.0     546.00
2021-09     9.0     1471.50
2021-09     11.0    1535.16
```

The `time` column represent for how many months the `value` is being payed from the start of `date`. So for example the first row remains the same, the second row remains the same as there is nothing to add, but the third row would be the `value` + `6600` because from the second row, the value of `6600` is being payed from `2021-08` to `2022-02`

I am unsure how can I achieve this, my idea was to create a new data frame:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='2021-08', end=datetime.datetime.now(), freq='M'), columns=['value'])
new_df['commission'] = 0
```

And fill it somehow while iterating through the main `df` so that the end result should look like this:

```
leased  value
2021-08 22.50 + 6600
2021-09 6600 + 1057.62 + 646.35 + 311.76 + 3982.50 + 900.00 + 546.00 + 1471.50 + 1535.16
2021-10 6600 + 646.35 + 311.76 + 3982.50 + 900.00 + 546.00 + 1471.50 + 1535.16
2021-11 6600 + 3982.50 + 900.00 + 546.00 + 1471.50 + 1535.16
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a monthly period, [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows, increment the periods with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
# make period
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')

# repeat the values, aggregate
out = (
 df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['time'].add(1))]
   .assign(date=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(d['date']))
   .groupby('date', as_index=False)['value'].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
       date     value
0   2021-08   6622.50
1   2021-09  17050.89
2   2021-10  15993.27
3   2021-11  15346.92
4   2021-12  15035.16
5   2022-01  11052.66
6   2022-02   3552.66
7   2022-03   3552.66
8   2022-04   3552.66
9   2022-05   3006.66
10  2022-06   3006.66
11  2022-07   1535.16
12  2022-08   1535.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

Here we use `map()` and `np.arange()` to create a list that we will `explode()`. We then add the months to each date and `groupby()` date

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
(df.assign(time = df['time'].add(1).map(lambda x: np.arange(1,x+1)))
.explode('time').assign(date = lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: r['date']+pd.offsets.DateOffset(months = r['time']-1),axis=1))
.groupby('date')['value'].sum())
```

Output:

```
date
2021-08-01     6622.50
2021-09-01    17050.89
2021-10-01    15993.27
2021-11-01    15346.92
2021-12-01    15035.16
2022-01-01    11052.66
2022-02-01     3552.66
2022-03-01     3552.66
2022-04-01     3552.66
2022-05-01     3006.66
2022-06-01     3006.66
2022-07-01     1535.16
2022-08-01     1535.16
```